# How can i get r-g-b values for each pixel by using c?

Tags: c, rgb, bmp

I need to do color space conversion from RGB to YCbCr  in C for my homework. First, I get r-g-b values for each pixel of a bmp file. Then,  use the code shown below. But I can not get r-g-b values of pixels. How can I do that?

```
struct YCbCr ycbcr;
ycbcr.Y = (float)(0.2989 * fr + 0.5866 * fg + 0.1145 * fb);
ycbcr.Cb = (float)(-0.1687 * fr - 0.3313 * fg + 0.5000 * fb);
ycbcr.Cr = (float)(0.5000 * fr - 0.4184 * fg - 0.0816 * fb);
```

Comment: Depends on the .bmp file and on how you read it... but if the .bmp file isn't compressed, it's usually pretty straightforward (still more than one way the pixels could be stored, though).  You haven't shown how you try to read the values, or given much information about the .bmp file.

Comment: I read pixels like this        for(i=0;i<resim1.width;i++) for(j=0;j<resim1.height;j++) fread(&dizi[i][j],1,1,fp);  indeed, it is a ppm file but i should convert it to bmp file because of the hw's instruction

Comment: There are image manipulation libraries available that will let you read a bmp file into an array.

Comment: The ppm file format is easy to read, it's a good exercise to do it without a library.